# How to use MySQL search against variable

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am trying to create stored procedure that will find similar strings using match function.
I know that match doesn't work against column values based on this piece of documentation

> The argument to AGAINST() must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

Here is the procedure I am trying to make:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE findSimilar (IN searchText VARCHAR(1000), OUT result INT)
begin
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE title varchar(1000) DEFAULT "";
    DEClARE curTitle
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT title FROM news;
        
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
       
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE match_news (title varchar(1000), similarity double);
    
    OPEN curTitle;
    
    getNews: LOOP
        FETCH curTitle INTO title;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getNews;
        END IF;
    
        insert into match_news(title, similarity)
        select title, match(searchText) against title as similarity;
    
    END LOOP getNews;

    select * from match_news
    order by similarity desc
    
    return 0

END//
```

In this part of code I get SQL syntax error:

```
select title, match(searchText) against title as similarity;
```

Comment: Try `select title, match(searchText) against(title) as similarity;`

Comment: @bato3 I get SQL Error [1210] [HY000]: Incorrect arguments to MATCH while executing procedure this way

Comment: In the previous comment, I wanted to point out to you that you have a syntax error. Remember: You can do most of the inquiries in the procedure yourself.
**And now I noticed** that you are not referring to the table. A `match () against ()` requires a `fulltext` index. So you can't call variables directly in the cursor and you have to apply another temporary table.

Comment: Another thing: Why are you generating a cursor for the title, how can you directly fill the table with data...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bato3 I have found the solution.

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE findSimilar (IN searchText NVARCHAR(1000))
begin   
    
    select n1.title, searchText, (match(n1.title) against (searchText)) as similarity
    from news n1
    order by similarity desc;

END//
```